# How to link or unlink feature image in blogger using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

here is the jquery i used to get the feature image in blogger

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
// the order goes container -> body -> surround -> image
var body = $('.post-body').first();
var container = $(body).parent();
var image = $(body).find('img').first();
var surround = $(image).parent();
$(surround).prependTo(container);
});
//]]></script>
</b:if>
```

1. but in all of this code the image appear but it hyperlinked to the image url and i just want to remove it, how do i do this..
2. how to apply css on it. 
   thanks in advance ,...

Comment: can you share html code also

Comment: in  blogger there is no html, its xml code, if you need complete template then tell me ?/

Comment: in blogger, you are using xml codes not html, if you need complete template i give you, i applied it on my [nclist](http://www.nclist.xyz) website. you can also extract using inspect element. or if you need anything just reply. you may go to any post and will see that img appear but its not alligned, not applied any css, and most rough this its links to jpg image url, that what i want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if we could see some HTML. even though you configure it in XML, it will render as HTML. You can inspect the element using your web browser and view the HTML that is generated. This can help us identify what steps are required.

Without seeing the HTML, these are the best suggestions I can give:

Use jQuery's [.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method if the hyperlink is represented by an anchor tag. You can use this method to remove the href attribute from the anchor tag. I would try this. If this doesn't work, then you may want to add a listener to the onclick event and return false

You can use a similar approach to add a class attribute, or style attribute, and add CSS that way.

It could also be Javascript that is listening for an on click event (unlikely though). In this case, you can use the [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method in jQuery or the [.removeEventListener()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp) event in JS. You will want to remove the click event.